# /tmp is not full but session_write_close() gives "write failed: No space left on device"

Tags: php, session, phpmyadmin, freebsd

phpMyAdmin is giving "Warning: session_write_close() [function.session-write-close]: write failed: No space left on device" but it does not appear that /tmp is full.

OS is FreeBSD 8.0 (yes it's old).

```
$ df -h /tmp
Filesystem     Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/ad4s1e    989M     53M    857M     6%    /tmp
```

What should be my next move?

Comment: Have you verified that [session_save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) is `/tmp`, and its permissions are set correctly?

Comment: just do a regular `df -h` and see what partition is full, likely this is same partition within which your `session_save_path` lies.

Comment: Yep, PHP session_save_path() reports '/tmp'  `df -h` does show issues with other partition.  Thanks!  Mike- you want to add as an answer?

Comment: Note that a partition can also be full if there are no inodes left on the filesystem, because of many small files.

Comment: Sven brings up a good point. Check `df -hi` to see that you're not out of inodes.